# Using subprocess module with curl command

Tags: python, curl, subprocess

I'm getting the error: **function' object is unsubscriptable** when using the subprocess module with curl command.

```
cmd (subprocess.check_call ['curl -X POST -u "opt:gggguywqydfydwfh" ' + Url + 'job/%s/%s/promotion/' % (job, Num)]).
```

I am calling this using the function.

```
def cmd(sh):
  proc = subprocess.Popen(sh, shell=True, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE).
```

Can anyone point out the problem?

Comment: Shelling out to `curl` instead of using a library like `requests` could be considered the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You forgot the parens with `check_call`:

```
subprocess.check_call(["curl", "-X", "POST", "-u", "opt:gggguywqydfydwfh",Url + 'job/%s/%s/promotion/' % (job, Num)])
```

You are trying to `subprocess.check_call[...`

You are also passing it to your function, `check_call` returns the exit code so you are trying to pass `0` to your Popen call as `sh` which is going to fail.

If you actually want the output, forget the function and use `check_output`, you also need to pass a list of args:

```
out = subprocess.check_output(["curl", "-X", "POST", "-u", "opt:gggguywqydfydwfh", Url + 'job/%s/%s/promotion/' % (job, Num)])
```

Either way passing check_call to Popen is not the way to go

Comment: Also, you should specify the command arguments as separate list elements: `['curl', '-X', 'POST', ... ]`.

Comment: typo: subprocess.check_*output*

Comment: @augurar, yes, did not realise they weren't.