# how to post a curl command using python

Tags: python-3.x, curl, cmd, ibm-watson, watson-assistant

I need help with this.. Basically i need to use this command. This is the example given using CURL. All i need to do is simply paste this in cmd and it does its job.

```
curl \
-H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST \
-u "{username}":"{password}" \
-d "{\"dialog_node\":\"greeting\",\"conditions\":\"#hello\",\"output\":{\"text\":\"Hi! How can I help you?\"},\"title\":\"greeting\"}" "https://gateway-s.watsonplatform.net/conversation/api/v1/workspaces/bec28d8f-18c1-4e97-8d08-9c842c658b51/dialog_nodes?version=2017-05-26"
```

The URL documentation can be found here: 
https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/conversation/api/v1/?curl#create_dialognode

The problem now is that i want to run this in a python script instead of in CMD.. i have searched google and stackOverflow for a few hours now.. but i cant seem to find the right answer..

So far i seen ppl using 
1.requests
2.urllib
3.urllib2
4.pycurl
5.subprocess

I want to do it the right way. What is the best way to run the above command in a python script and how do i do it?

Also i am using python 3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Likes Simon O'Doherty said, you can use the [Python SDK](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/python-sdk) for using Conversation service. It is really the best practice to use the service, using the SDK or `http` [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/).

> "If something's worth doing, it's worth doing right, right?". So what
>   you're asking is *"how do I run this other program, from within my
>   program, just to make a measly little web request?"*.
>
> You can use cURL command, yes, you can. But it hardly looks very
>   Pythonic. That's a lot of work just for one little request. Python's
>   is more than it.

Author from the phrases [here](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1446048/ojford).

But, your question looks like you really want to use the `cURL` command inside your Python code, so, here is one example. In this case, you can use [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html).

Call the Converstation:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call(['curl', '-x', 'POST', '-H', '"Accept: application/json"', '-u', '{"userNameFromServiceCredentials:PasswordFromServiceCredentials" }', '"https://gateway-s.watsonplatform.net/conversation/api/v1/workspaces/bec28d8f-18c1-4e97-8d08-9c842c658b51/dialog_nodes?version=2017-05-26"'])
```

**Important:** For send the message and getting the output, you need to use the function [`subprocess.check_output();`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#using-the-subprocess-module) like this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32038369/using-subprocess-module-with-curl-command). And send the message for the right router, your cURL command needs to looks like this example from [@German Atannasio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35685955/watson-dialog-curl-conversation-post-request-not-passing-form-data) and [@Pridkkett](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39595932/watson-conversation-api-giving-gateway-error-code-ercd04-invldchr-userid-from).

*Note:* This answer is just to tell what is the better way to you follow, and if you really wants to [use](https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/conversation/api/v1/?curl#send_message), one "Stone path" for you follow.

- API Reference for using Watson Conversation Service with [Python](https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/conversation/api/v1/?python#send_message).
- Requests documentation [here](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/).

Comment: hohoho thanks for the explanation cheers! i got what i needed thank you! :)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Watson Conversation, then you can just use the Python WDC SDK.

https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/python-sdk

For your example above it would be:

```
from watson_developer_cloud import ConversationV1

username = 'USERNAME',
password = 'PASSWORD',
version = '2017-05-26',
workspace_id = 'bec28d8f-18c1-4e97-8d08-9c842c658b51'
url = 'https://gateway-s.watsonplatform.net/conversation/api'

conversation = ConversationV1(
    username=username
    password=password,
    version=version,
    url=url
}

dialog_nodes = []

welcome_node = {
    'output': { 
        'text': { 'values': [ 'Welcome!' ],
                  'selection_policy': 'sequential' 
        } 
    },
    'parent': None,
    'context': None,
    'metadata': None,
    'next_step': None,
    'conditions': 'welcome',
    'dialog_node': 'Welcome',
    'previous_sibling': None
}

dialog_nodes.append(welcome_node)

# this appends to the previous node above, set by previous_sibling
node = {
    'dialog_node': 'greeting',
    'conditions': '#hello',
    'context': None,
    'metadata': None,
    'next_step': None,
    'output':{ 
        'text': { 'values': [ 'Hi! How can I help you?' ]},
                  'selection_policy': 'sequential'
        }
    },
    'title': 'greeting ',
    'previous_sibling': 'Welcome',
    'parent': None
}

dialog_nodes.append(node)

## Update the workspace.
response = conversation.update_workspace(
    workspace_id=workspace_id, 
    dialog_nodes=dialog_nodes
)

print(response)
```

This call is an all or nothing, so if you have existing nodes it will delete them. The reason being is the SDK doesn't have the individual node editing. But this is a faster way to do it, rather then editing a single node (if you have more then one node).

If you want to make the individual call, then you will need to use something like `requests`, until the SDK is updated.

Example (using same variables from above):

```
import requests
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth

endpoint = '{}/v1/workspaces/{}/dialog_nodes?version={}'.format(url,workspace_id,version)

basic_auth = HTTPBasicAuth(username, password)

# Change the condition to always execute. 
node['conditions'] = 'true'

response = requests.post(url=endpoint, auth=basic_auth, json=node)
```

Comment: disclaimer: I wrote that by hand, I am not sure if it compiles. :)

Comment: the first code box above was something u typed yourself?

Comment: Well I copied the values from the original post, but otherwise yes.

Comment: well its cool thanks for ur time in helping me type it out! But imma still use the curl as of now cause i have like 1000+ dialogs and to edit just one, running the entire thing will be a little cumbersome. But hey thanks for the effort Simon!  Could u expand the second code box u did like where do i put the parent, context, siblings and so on..

Comment: The bottom code requires the top code pieces. The easiest way to figure out how to structure dialog nodes is to create a sample dialog tree in Conversation, then export it.

Answer (score 0):

In python3 when sending files with pycurl, I want to understand why do I have to send the binary file directly
instead of providing its path

IBM Watson

```
#coding:utf-8

import certifi
import pycurl
import io

response = io.BytesIO()
c = pycurl.Curl()

#"apikey" is a key word

user = "apikey"
pwd = "YouRaPiKey"

#the file you want to submit
with open("path_to_file/audio-file.flac","rb") as f:
    audiofile = f.read()

c.setopt(c.URL,  "https://api. .... /.... /.. /v1/recognize")
c.setopt(pycurl.USERPWD, "{}:{}".format(user, pwd))
c.setopt(c.WRITEFUNCTION, response.write)
c.setopt(c.HTTPHEADER, ['Content-Type: audio/flac','Transfer-Encoding: chunked'])
c.setopt(c.POSTFIELDS, audiofile)
c.setopt(c.CAINFO,certifi.where())


c.perform()
c.close()

body = response.getvalue()
body = body.decode('iso-8859-1')

print(body)
```